# Twilio Flex, Intercept Incoming Messages in order to send Slack Notifications

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I currently have Twilio Flex set up but need to intercept all incoming messages in order to send slack notifications to reps, if they're offline and need to respond.

Is there a way to intercept (using a webhook) only Incoming messages so that I can send those slack notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you go into your Flex project to the [Studio dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/dashboard) you will find three flows, including the Messaging Flow. Incoming messages are directed to this Flow.

If you open the Messaging Flow you will see that by default it sends the message straight to Flex.

You can add a widget in here to [invoke a Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function) before sending the message onto Flex. [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) allow you to write Node.js to perform custom tasks, like sending a Slack notification.